# Dockerfile USER step is always missing cache

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my docker file, this step never hits cache and always yields new intermediate container:

```
USER $USERNAME
```

When running with `docker build --rm=false .` the output around the `USER` always misses the cache and always yields a different hash, even though the preceding hash is identical.

```
 ---> b2ee21c9959f
Step 38/55 : USER $USERNAME
 ---> Running in 6ea8b1f6df65
 ---> 86640ea527b0
```

```
 ---> b2ee21c9959f
Step 38/55 : USER $USERNAME
 ---> Running in c9e822b114b0
 ---> e289bdbf5a1d
```

I don't understand why it keeps missing the cache. Also why is `USER` not idempotent?

**EDIT: Turns out that that $USERNAME is empty, because the ARG was not declared. Still weird that it would miss the cache.**

Diff of full output: https://www.diffchecker.com/c5Ftyx01

Dockerfile:

```
ARG METEOR_VERSION=1.10.2
ARG NODE_VERSION=13.11.0
ARG NVM_VERSION=0.35.3
ARG METEOR_PROJECT_PATH=examples/leaderboard
ARG USERNAME=meteor-deploy
ARG GROUPNAME=$USERNAME
ARG PULUMI_PROJECT_NAME

FROM empiricaly/meteor:$METEOR_VERSION as meteor-with-user

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ARG GROUPNAME
RUN groupadd "$GROUPNAME"

ARG USERNAME
ENV HOME "/home/$USERNAME"
RUN useradd -g "$GROUPNAME" -d "$HOME" -ms /bin/bash  "$USERNAME"

USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR $HOME

ARG METEOR_VERSION
RUN meteor --release "$METEOR_VERSION" --version

FROM meteor-with-user as meteor-nvm
ENV NVM_DIR "$HOME/.nvm"
ARG NODE_VERSION
RUN mkdir "$NVM_DIR"

# Install nvm with node and npm
ARG NVM_VERSION
RUN curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v$NVM_VERSION/install.sh" | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH   $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH        $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm --version

FROM meteor-nvm as meteor-nvm-pulumi
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | bash

ENV PULUMI_PATH $HOME/.pulumi/bin
ENV PATH        $PATH:$PULUMI_PATH

ENV PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE meteor-pulumi

RUN pulumi version

FROM meteor-nvm-pulumi as local-meteor-deploy
# XXX --chown doesn't support dynamic arguments, yet.
#COPY --chown=$USERNAME:$GROUPNAME . meteor-deploy
COPY . meteor-deploy
USER root
RUN chown -R "$USERNAME:$GROUPNAME" "$HOME/meteor-deploy"
USER $USERNAME

WORKDIR $HOME/meteor-deploy

RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && npm install
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && npm run build:js \
    && npm link

FROM local-meteor-deploy as meteor-project
WORKDIR $HOME

ARG METEOR_PROJECT_PATH
# XXX --chown doesn't support dynamic arguments, yet.
#ADD --chown=$USERNAME:$GROUPNAME $METEOR_PROJECT_URL meteor-project
ADD $METEOR_PROJECT_PATH meteor-project
USER root
RUN chown -R $USERNAME:$GROUPNAME meteor-project
USER $USERNAME

WORKDIR $HOME/meteor-project

RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && npm install -D "file://$HOME/meteor-deploy"
ARG PULUMI_PROJECT_NAME
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && npx meteor-deploy init $PULUMI_PROJECT_NAME && npm install

RUN pulumi login -l --non-interactive && pulumi stack init dev --non-interactive

FROM meteor-project
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && npx meteor-deploy stack configure default
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug.

Things to try:

1. Update to latest version of Docker, see if it fixes it.
2. Try to create minimal reproducer. Might help you catching something, but if you have minimal reproducer you can file bug at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues, or maybe find a workaround.

One potential workaround is trying the BuildKit backend, an alternative build backend.

1. Add `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.1-experimental` to first line of Dockerfile.
2. `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`
3. Run build.

Comment: `Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c`, seems fairly recent and release notes don't mention any related fixes for newer version. But if that behaviour is indeed not expected, then I think it is more likely I am doing something wrong rather than it being a bug.

Comment: I found that `$USERNAME` was empty. I guess this would be a way to reproduce the issue in isolation. Not sure if it is a bug though.